# How do I check / activate a certain feature in group policy editor via API / VB6?

Tags: api, windows-10, group-policy

I need to set the following feature in group policy editor on really many computers of the same model.

Computer configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Locations and Sensors -> Deactivate Sensors

And before I do this, I would like to check if it has not already been set.

Is there any way to do this via VB6 / API?

I have googled, and I didn't find any solution, only super complicated ones. Do I have to use AutoHotKey to do this? :-D

Thank you!

Edit:
I found a file here: C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicyUsers\Machine\comment.cmtx

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<policyComments xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" revision="1.0" schemaVersion="1.0" xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/CommentDefinitions">
  <policyNamespaces>
    <using prefix="ns0" namespace="Microsoft.Policies.Sensors"></using>
  </policyNamespaces>
  <comments>
    <admTemplate></admTemplate>
  </comments>
  <resources minRequiredRevision="1.0">
    <stringTable></stringTable>
  </resources>
</policyComments>
```

Perhaps I can just check for this file...

Edit 2:
This file doesn't seem to do anything. It merely shows the last change...

The real file seems to be C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicyUsers\Machine\Registry.pol

Answer (score 0):

Now I am just reading the said Registry.pol and overwriting it when necessary.
Requires admin right though.